# How to store data in a database using laravel

Tags: laravel

Please what is  wrong with this code...am a newbie and this task was given to complete, I watch YouTube and read online but I can seem to figure out how to store records in database ...

This is UserController

> ```
> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
> use Storage;
> use App\User;
>
> class UserController extends Controller {
> /**
>  * @return $this
>  */
> public function showUsersWithProperty() {
>
>     $users = User::all()->filter(function($user) {
>         return $user->properties->count();
>     });
>
>     return view('settings.manageusers')
>         ->with('users', $users);
> }
>
> public function editUser(Request $request, $id){
>     $users = User::all()->filter(function($user) {
>         return $user->properties->count();
>     });
>
>     $user = User::find($id);
>
>     return view('settings.manageusers')
>         ->with('users', $users)->with('editId', $user->id);
> }
>
> public function updateUser(Request $request, $id){
>     $input = $request;
>     $user = User::find($input->id);
>
>     if ($input->hasFile('userPic')) {
>         $image = $input->file('userPic');
>         $realname = pathinfo($input->file('userPic')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
>         $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
>         $new_name = time().".".$extension;
>         $image->storeAs('public/uploads', $new_name);
>         $path = Storage::url("uploads/" . $new_name);
>         $user->image_url = $path;
>     }
>
>     $user->first_name = $input->fname;
>     $user->last_name = $input->lname;
>     $user->pin = $input->changePin; 
>
>     if($input->deactivate =="on" || $input->deleteUser =="on"){
>         $user->account_status = 0;
>     } else {
>         $user->account_status = 1;
>     }
>
>     $user->save();
>
>     return redirect()->route('manageUsers')->with('status', "User Updated");
>
> } }
> ```

This my Route

> Route::post('/settings/updateUser/',
>   'UserController@updateUser')->name("user.update");
>   Route::get('/settings/updateUser/',
>   'UserController@updateUser')->name("user.update");

Comment: and what is your error?

Comment: First of all, fix your routes. Don't use the same name for different routes, and for the GET route, make another function called `getUser` instead and only retrieve user details here. Update user details in `updateUser` function only.

Comment: this is the error

symfony/Component%20/HttpKernel/Exception/Method

NO MESSAGE